# JavaScript algorithm for removing the background of a shape in a canvas

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, rgb

I use this formula to turn my shapes into grayscale.

```
R x 0.2126 + G x 0.7152 + B x 0.0722
```

Now which algorithm I can use use to remove the background of a shape in a canvas like this.

[image]

Or this.

[image]

In this specific case, my goal is to obtain the first symbol ("a") and the second symbol ("p") with a transparent background.

Comment: Simple thresholding might be sufficient. Performing histogram normalization beforehand would make that more robust.